# Android: My location button doesn't work on Android 6.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

Everything works fine in other androids, but in 6.0 MyLocationButton doesn't do anything. here's my code

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap
                .setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                        Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
                        if (location == null) {
                           checkLocationSettings();
                           return true;
                        }

                        LatLng locationLatLng = new LatLng(location
                                .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        setMarkerToMap(locationLatLng );
                        //other staff
                        return false;
});

protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
                .checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest);
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                try {
                    status.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

What can cause this problem? I guess it has to do something with new permissions(in Android 6.0), but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried to check ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission inside OnClickListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer these link and add permissions on runtime.

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-
marshmallow/

Or try these

Create the verifyStoragePermissions()method and called in onCreateView() 
of Activity

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
   Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
   Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation};
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity)
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
           Manifest.permission.AccessCoarseLocation);
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
            1001  // pass any request code
    );
}
```